# django data migration - class variable unavailable via get_model()

Tags: django, orm, django-migrations

I'm trying to update some database records via a Django data migration, using the following migration file:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import IntegrityError, migrations

def exclude_pending_drivers(apps, schema_edition):
    Driver = apps.get_model("team", "Driver")
    pending_drivers = Driver.objects.filter(type=Driver.PENDING)
    for driver in pending_drivers:
        driver.show_in_app = False
    Driver.objects.bulk_update(pending_drivers, ['show_in_app'])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('team', '0002_add_show_in_app_to_driver'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(exclude_pending_drivers),
    ]
```

I'm getting an error when I run it:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Driver' has no attribute 'PENDING'
```

`PENDING` is defined as a class variable in the model:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    PENDING = 1
    CONFIRMED = 2

    show_in_app = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # etc
```

I can run the exact migration code above in a `manage.py shell` without errors, and it also runs fine if I use `from team.models import Driver` instead of `apps.get_model("team", "Driver")` (although obviously that's not advised).

What gives? It looks like the Driver class, when it's included via `apps.get_model()`, is different to a straight `import`, but surely that's not the case??

Answer (score 0):

Models are registered in `apps`. There's `django.apps.apps` that's using the "latest" model state, and the apps that are provided in your `RunPython`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/c3d7a71f836f7cfe8fa90dd9ae95b37b660d5aae/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py#L193

The `apps` in `RunPython` are generated using the `from_state`. In other words, when Django needs to run 10 migrations and you need `RunPython` in 7th, it provides the "state" of the database from the 7th migration. It doesn't matter if you run them one by one every month or all at once - the state of the 7th migration will be the same for all models across your entire project.

That's all that's passed in the migration - the state of the model (and all the other models). It can't deserialize into the model with your business logic, as it changes over time. Any constants or methods are not available during the migration. It's best to copy as much as possible into the migration itself. It doesn't matter if it's ugly, as long as you can rerun the migration over time and expect the same outcome.

> It looks like the Driver class, when it's included via apps.get_model(), is different to a straight import

If you inspect, you should see it says something like `__fake__.Driver`. Again, it's the representation of your table, not the model itself.

> Driver.PENDING

I never liked putting constants/choices in your models. If I was to handle such migration, I'd first create a choices module

```
# choices.py

class DriverStatus(models.TextChoices):
    PENDING = "pending"
```

Then in your migration

```
try:
    from app_name.choices import DriverStatus
    PENDING = DriverStatus.PENDING
except ImportError:
    PENDING = "pending"
```

Now you can migrate `pending` drivers and the state of your migration is local.